# How to access to item from HTML Node [Vue.js]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have:

Vue app data:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        items: [
            {id: 1, text: 'one', other_data: {}},
            {id: 2, text: 'two', other_data: {}},
            {id: 3, text: 'three', other_data: {}}
        ]
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<div v-for="item in items" id="my_items">
    <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
</div>
```

And i need to access from one item by external JS code like next:

```
let item_node = document.getElementById('my_items').children[1]; // get 2nd child node of #my_items
item_node.__vuedata__ // must be a 2nd item from items in Vue data. {id: 2, text: 'two'...
```

How to do like this?

Comment: what is your problem? this sounds like you want a code review.

Comment: No. I need to get Vue data item by HTML node. The data element from whith the HTML node was generated. I wanna to know, its can be possible by Vue, or i need to do other for accessing data object from generated HTML node.

Comment: you posted us some code. which is great. but what's wrong with the code? what is the actual result and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Vue recommends to use `ref` over ID and classes for DOM references. We use `ref` as a replacement for id. Since it is used on top of the v-for directive, all child elements are now referenced as an array of the ref. So every `span` will now be `hello[0] - hello[n]` The mounted code outputs the `item.text` for first child as it uses 0.

I added a click listener, every time you click the element, the value of `item` is passed to the method. Here you can extract all values and do whatever manipulation you require. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" ref='hello' @click="logItem(item)">
      <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
        items: [
            {id: 1, text: 'one', other_data: {}},
            {id: 2, text: 'two', other_data: {}},
            {id: 3, text: 'three', other_data: {}}
        ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logItem: (item) => console.log(item)
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$refs.hello[0].innerText)
  }
};
</script>
```